# Switching jobs after a Schengen visa application

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I have obtained a letter from the employer stating that the company has no objection for my travel to the Schengen area. I haven't yet resigned from the current company but I won't be employed with the company during the travel duration. I might be employed with a different company at that time and that is not decided yet.

Is there going to be a problem with this scenario? Should I wait and join the other firm and get a new letter and then apply for a visa? I fear that I won't have sufficient time for a new application in this case (10 - 15 days maximum).

What if I use the current employer's letter and obtain the visa? Can the current employer claim later on after I resign that the letter is no longer valid and that I cannot use it for the visa?

Please suggest.

Comment: "a letter from the employer stating that the company has no objection for my travel to the Schengen area" What's that? How can a company even have any objections?

Comment: @bipll I don't know but that's what is written on their website. I think it's more like a leave approval.

Comment: An exit visa? :-\

Comment: @bipll tourist visa

Comment: In which country is this happening? Why do you need a letter from some company?

Comment: @Neusser This is happening for Swiss visa. They need some sort of guarantee that I'm employed and would come back and resume working at my home country (India).

Comment: Hi, can you please share what happened then? Did you get a visa?

Comment: @user3148290 Yes I got the visa.